# Incrementing Values Using Sed/Awk or Other Tool/Utility

Tags: bash, math, awk, sed, increment

I would like to use sed/awk to have numbers increase in a sequence (there are multiple numbers in the script).

So let's say I have the following code:

```
samplefilename_15.format 
samplefilename_20.format
samplefilename_25.format
```

See how all of these increase by five? Is there a way to increase all of the numbers (15, 20, and 25) by say five through sed/awk, or another method? So, when I run a command/script, the numbers become (20,25,30).

Thanks for any help.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @Juandelahoz - Change the numbers in a single file by a set integer. This is to prevent me having to create tens of files with sets of numbers that have all the changes. If you need more explanation, please say so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are free to use `perl`:

```
perl -ne 's/(?<=_)(\d+)(?=\.)/($1+5)/e && print' filename
```

Output:

```
samplefilename_20.format
samplefilename_25.format
samplefilename_30.format
```

To edit the file:

```
perl -ne 's/(?<=_)(\d+)(?=\.)/($1+5)/e && print' -i filename
```

Use global modifier if you have multiple entries on same line to be modified.

```
perl -ne 's/(?<=_)(\d+)(?=\.)/($1+5)/ge && print' -i filename
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there anyway to do this so that each time the numbers increase by five, and not just the first time the command is ran?

Comment: @hallettwx do you want to modify your file?

Comment: Yes, that would be awesome.

Comment: Thank you. How would this code be modified to be applied to say, two instances of samplefilename_20.format. In the code I just ran, the change is applied to the first instance, but not the second or third.

Comment: @hallettwx if you have multiple entries on same line and want to modify them all, add a global modifier.

Comment: Yes, I have codecodecode samplefilename_20.format morecodemorecode then another samplefilename_20.format, if that makes any sense.

Comment: @hallettwx I have updated my answer. If you still have some difficulty, please update your question so that all of them can be looked simultaneously.

Comment: I have upvoted/marked your answer as correct. Thank you very much!

Comment: @hallettwx: Since the script now modifies the values in place, make sure that you don't **accidentally** run the script twice, when you wanted to run it once... (Just a caution.)

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '{
    if(match($0, /_[0-9]+\./)) {
        a = substr($0, 0, RSTART)
        b = 5 + substr($0, RSTART + 1, RLENGTH - 2)
        c = substr($0, RSTART + RLENGTH - 1)
        $0 = a b c }
    print
}'
```

Output:

```
samplefilename_25.format
samplefilename_30.format
samplefilename_35.format
```